# Fingerprint GUI does not detect fingerprint device in ASUS Vivobook S

Tags: drivers, 18.04, fingerprint-reader

The fingerprint device was working with Windows. But lately, I have shifted to Ubuntu. I have installed these :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

I logged out and logged in and opened fingerprint GUI but it says no device found.

Result of lsusb is this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to enable fingerprint?